# Testing global constructors | Satisfy jslint

Tags: javascript, jslint, qunit

```
/*global
    test: true,
    equal: true,
*/

(function () {
    "use strict";
    test("each() and internals", function () {
        var globals = [
                new Array(),
                new Object(),
                new String(),
                new Number(),
                new Function(),
                new Boolean(),
                new Date(),
                new RegExp()
            ],
            ...
```

I'm writing some QUnit tests, which I want to pass jslint.  I want to use a set of Global Objects as these are distinctly different from their Literal representations.

Jslint does not like any of these except the last 2.  I did not see an option to relax jslint's anality.

Yes, I want my functional tests to pass jslint ( not jshint ).  Yes I want to use the Object Constructor and not the literal for some of my tests.

**Failed Tests**

```
Use the array literal notation [].

                new Array(),

line 31 character 21
Use the object literal notation {} or Object.create(null).

                new Object(),

line 32 character 21
Do not use String as a constructor.

                new String(),

line 33 character 21
Do not use Number as a constructor.

                new Number(),

line 34 character 29
The Function constructor is eval.

                new Function(),

line 35 character 21
Do not use Boolean as a constructor.

                new Boolean(),
```

Comment: Note that using an array literal and an object literal will have exactly the same effect, so that could reduce your set of errors a bit. If you require objects rather than literal values for the others though, I think you're just going to have to live with the warnings. Or switch to JSHint.

Comment: ...finally realized that if you are testing things, you are on a certain level, purposefully, writing bad code, so I'm not going to use syntax analysis on test code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the following [`switch` statement in the JSLint source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L2790):

```
switch (c.string) {
case 'Object':
    token.warn('use_object');
    break;
case 'Array':
    if (next_token.id === '(') {
        // ...
        if (next_token.id !== ')') {
            // ...
        } else {
            token.warn('use_array');
        }
        // ...
    }
    token.warn('use_array');
    break;
case 'Number':
case 'String':
case 'Boolean':
case 'Math':
case 'JSON':
    c.warn('not_a_constructor');
    break;
case 'Function':
    if (!option.evil) {
        next_token.warn('function_eval');
    }
    break;
case 'Date':
case 'RegExp':
case 'this':
    break;
default:
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, there are no options to switch these checks on or off, except in the case of the `Function` constructor. That warning can be turned off by setting the `evil` option to `true`.

In your case, you can safely replace calls to the `Array` and `Object` constructor with their literal counterparts. For the other warnings, you have no choice but to ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

From JSLint instructions

http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

> JSLint does not expect to see the wrapper forms new Number, new
>   String, new Boolean.
>
> JSLint does not expect to see new Object. Use {} instead.
>
> JSLint does not expect to see new Array. Use [] instead.

And it looks like there is no option that controls that

Answer (score 1):

Jslint doubts you really want to do that, since using the constructors will make comparisons fail unexpectedly:

```
var s1 = new String('hi');
var s2 = new String('hi');

// but s1 == s2 is false now!  Not to mention 'hi' === s1!
```

More detail: http://jslinterrors.com/do-not-use-a-as-a-constructor/